# Flurry for iOS: Remove FlurryAdBanner from screen

Tags: ios, flurry

How can I remove a *FlurryAdBanner* in iOS? I'm searching for something similar to `[FlurryAds removeAdFromSpace:space]`;
This is my FlurryAdBanner integration:

```
FlurryAdBanner * flurryAdBanner = nil;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    flurryAdBanner = [[FlurryAdBanner alloc] initWithSpace:MY_SPACE_NAME_FOR_TOP_BANNER];
    flurryAdBanner.adDelegate = self;
    [flurryAdBanner fetchAndDisplayAdInView:self.view viewControllerForPresentation:self];
}


-(void)adBannerDidFetchAd:(FlurryAdBanner *) localadBanner
{
    [localadBanner displayAdInView:self.view viewControllerForPresentation:self];
}

-(IBAction)removeFluryAd:(id)sender
{

    // Not working - but I'm searching for code, that removes the Banner
    [FlurryAds removeAdFromSpace:MY_SPACE_NAME_FOR_TOP_BANNER];
}
```